# Can't manage to set brightness on desktop Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: brightness, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a ***desktop***.

I tried the following and none of them worked:

```
$ xbacklight -dec 10
$ xdotool key "alt+r" XF86MonBrightnessDown
$ echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
tee: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness: No such file or directory
400
```

First two didn't throw any errors. They just didn't work.

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, there is not a single driver to change backlighting for all hardware.

Apparently `xbacklight` tries to set it through `acpi_video0`, which may not be the right one for your setting.

Your `xdotool` command tries to set it by simulating a keyboard touch press, I guess there are many reasons it could fail (and no error, since the keypress was simulated anyway).

The last command indicate that `intel_backlight` is probably not the right driver either.  BTW, **`sudo tee` commands can be dramatically harmful for your system, be sure to understand exactly what they do before applying them**.  Here it is supposed to replace the whole content of the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file with 400 (which in this case is a good thing to try, provided the file exists).

Check which folders are in `/sys/class/backlight/` and try to adapt the last command to the folders that are actually there.

But the issue may be elsewhere, you may want to check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283068/26952).

[[Credits.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1207348#p1207348)]